# How to decrypt this javascript code

Tags: encryption, javascript, decryption

I can't decrypt it.

Please advise me.

javascript code

```
var _$_5e56=["\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x75\x72\x6C","\x69\x64","\x6D\x75\x6B\x61\x2E\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x28\x29","\x65\x78\x65\x63\x75\x74\x65\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x74\x61\x62\x73","\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x23\x6E\x6F\x74\x2D\x66\x62\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65","\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"]

$(document)[_$_5e56[10]](function()
{
    chrome[_$_5e56[6]][_$_5e56[9]]({active:true},function(a)
    {
        if(a[0][_$_5e56[2]][_$_5e56[1]](_$_5e56[0])!= -1)
        {
            chrome[_$_5e56[6]][_$_5e56[5]](a[0][_$_5e56[3]],{code:_$_5e56[4]})
        }
        else 
        {
            $(_$_5e56[8])[_$_5e56[7]]()
        }
```

Comment: Flagging as off topic because "This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.".

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't encrypted, though it slightly obfuscated. The first line of the code:

`var _$_5e56=["\x66\x61\x63\x65\x62\x6F\x6F\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x75\x72\x6C","\x69\x64","\x6D\x75\x6B\x61\x2E\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x28\x29","\x65\x78\x65\x63\x75\x74\x65\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x74\x61\x62\x73","\x73\x68\x6F\x77","\x23\x6E\x6F\x74\x2D\x66\x62\x2D\x70\x61\x67\x65","\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"]`

simply defines an array of strings by using hex-encoded ASCII.  (E.g., `\x66` is `f`, etc.).  Thus that line simplifies to

`_$_5e56 = ["facebook.com", "indexOf", "url", "id", "muka.open()", "executeScript", "tabs", "show", "#not-fb-page", "query", "ready"]`.

The variable name `_$_5e56` is a tad odd, so I'm just going to rename it `arr` for array.  Then the rest of the script is (after adding a few characters that appear to have been forgotten by the OP):

```
$(document)[arr[10]](function()
{
    chrome[arr[6]][arr[9]]({active:true},function(a)
    {
        if(a[0][arr[2]][arr[1]](arr[0])!= -1)
        {
            chrome[arr[6]][arr[5]](a[0][arr[3]],{code:arr[4]})
        }
        else 
        {
            $(arr[8])[arr[7]]()
        }
    })})
```

If we then perform the substitutions of the various values of `arr`

```
$(document)["ready"](function()
{
    chrome["tabs"]["query"]({active:true},function(a)
    {
        if(a[0]["url"]["indexOf"]("facebook.com")!= -1)
        {
            chrome["tabs"]["executeScript"](a[0]["id"],{code:"muka.open()"})
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#not-fb-page")["show"]()
        }
})})
```

Very roughly, this is using jquery `$(document).ready` to run the code inside the function when the document is run.  It uses the [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) permission (specifically [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) of a chrome javascript extension to get all the active tabs, and then on check if the URL of the first active tab has "facebook.com" anywhere in it.   (`a` is an array of all the active tabs, `a[0]` is the first active tab, `a[0]["url"]` is a string of the full URL of that tab and on a string the function `indexOf` returns -1 if the string parameter ("facebook.com" in this case) isn't present.

You should note in javascript that the more [common dot notation is basically equivalent to the array lookup notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets#answer-4968448) (the array lookup is slightly more general as you can use special characters inside the string being looked up that you couldn't use in the dot-notation).  For example, if you have a `some_str` defined, you can get the `length` or run the `indexOf` function on it by two methods:

```
> var some_str = "Hello world"
> some_str.length
11
> some_str["length"]
11
> some_str.indexOf("world")
6
> some_str["indexOf"]("world")
6
```

This would allow us further to simplify the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(active_tabs) {
        if(active_tabs[0].url.indexOf("facebook.com")!= -1) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(active_tabs[0].id,{code:"muka.open()"})
        } else {
            $("#not-fb-page").show()
        }
    })
})
```

When facebook.com is the first active tab, it executes the script `muka.open()` inside that tab, otherwise it shows the DOM element with the ID `not-fb-page` (that may have previously been hidden).  I'm not familiar with any `muka` javascript library; presumably this is defined elsewhere in the extension.

Comment: How is this security related?

Comment: @cremefraiche - Javascript obfuscation is very much a information security concern.  Sure this particular question/code isn't particularly enlightening (no idea what `muka.open` does), but the basic gist of how to understand and translate obfuscated JS is worth understanding for anyone interested in the security of their JS-enabled browser.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't, I just asked how.